# Performing empirical bayesian kriging in R

Tags: r, software-recommendations, kriging

I am trying to apply empirical bayesian kriging in R, but I cannot find a package that provides a function for EBK.

Does anyone know of any or should I use ArcGIS?

Comment: For software recommendations there is the [softwarerecs.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code based off a script by my colleague E. Spurgeon. I couldn't find anything for EBK but here is a different option for interpolating using inverse distance weighting with the idw() function from package phylin. There's got to be a more straight forward way but so far this is the only function for interpolation in R that has worked for me:

```
#load packages
require(ggplot2)
require(phylin)
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(rgeos)
library(sf)

#open shapefile for base map youl plot over
sort.grid <- st_read("Sortija Grid.shp")


# Extract bounding box coordinates from the shape file youre gonna plot over
bbox.sort <- st_bbox(sort.grid)


#draw polygon where interpolation will occur. In this case it is a rectangle that we draw by specifying coords of each corner. Last set of coords is the same as the initial to close the shape of the polygon.

array_locs_orderd <- matrix(c(bbox.sort["xmin"], bbox.sort["ymin"], 
                              bbox.sort["xmin"], bbox.sort["ymax"], 
                              bbox.sort["xmax"], bbox.sort["ymax"],
                              bbox.sort["xmax"], bbox.sort["ymin"], 
                              bbox.sort["xmin"], bbox.sort["ymin"]), #connect to initial point
                              nrow = 5, byrow = TRUE
                              ) 
array_outline_sf <- st_polygon(list(array_locs_orderd))
plot(array_outline_sf)

array_grid <- st_make_grid(array_outline_sf, n=c(100,100)) 
#can change the numbers to make grid boxes bigger - smaller nums = bigger box

#creating the points that will be filled in by the interpolation 

array_interp_pts_sf <- array_grid[array_outline_sf]
array_interp_pts <- rgeos::gCentroid(as(array_interp_pts_sf, "Spatial"), byid = TRUE)
colnames(array_interp_pts@coords) <- c("longitude", "latitude")


#make sure your df has no NAs
df <- na.omit(df[, c("Temp", "longitude", "latitude")])

  # Interpolating All Points
  temp_interp1 <- data.frame(idw(df[,"Temp"], df[,c("longitude", "latitude")], array_interp_pts@coords, p = 2))
  # added @coords here
  
  names(temp_interp1) <- c('Temp')
  temp_interp1$ID <- gsub("ID", "", rownames(temp_interp1)) 
  # added ID column so we could merge back with the polygon extents
  
  plot_data <- merge(st_coordinates(array_interp_pts_sf), temp_interp1, by.x = "L2", by.y = "ID") 
  # merge with the polygon extent points
  
  plot_data$coord_num <- rep(1:5) # group into polygon IDs (there are 5 coordinates listed for both X and Y)
  plot_data <- plot_data %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from = coord_num, values_from = c(X,Y)) %>% # convert rows with X and Y to columns with X and Y bounds
    rowwise() %>% # for each row... 
    mutate(polygon_list = list(st_polygon(list(cbind(c(X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4, X_5), # make a polygon using these bounds
                                                     c(Y_1, Y_2, Y_3, Y_4, Y_5)))))) %>% 
    st_as_sf(crs = 4326) # and assign as WGS84
  
  
#keep only parts of interpolated heatmap that are in the ocean
  plot_data2 <- st_intersection(plot_data, bse)
    

#### Set Temp range####

max(plot_data2$Temp) 
min(plot_data2$Temp)
myPalette <- colorRampPalette(rev(brewer.pal(11, "Spectral")))
sc <- scale_colour_gradientn(colours = myPalette(100), limits=c(27,30))

sc_fill <- scale_fill_gradientn(colours = myPalette(100), limits = c(27,30))

  # Visualizing Interpolation
p.Sort.Agg <- ggplot() + 
   geom_sf(data = bse, color = "black",  fill = "lightblue") +# changed this plotting feature to plot the polygons we created
 geom_sf(data = plot_data2, aes(fill = Temp),  color = NA) + 
 xlim(c(bbox.sort["xmin"], bbox.sort["xmax"])) +
 ylim(c(bbox.sort["ymin"], bbox.sort["ymax"])) + 
  theme_classic() +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "darkseagreen3")) +
  scale_size(range = c(1, 20)) +
    xlab("Longitude") +
    ylab("Latitude") +
    sc +
    sc_fill
```

If you figure out a way for EBK, please let me know.